# Linear Algebra: $ span\{S\} \cap span\{T\} \subset span\{S \cap T\} $

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I posted a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129276/span-s-cap-t-subset-span-s-cap-span-t/2129286?noredirect=1#comment4379241_2129286)

But as the title suggests, I'm trying to show that the converse is true.

Here's what I have: 
let $y \in span\{S\} \cap span\{T\}$, then $y=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...+c_nv_n$, where $c$ is in a field, and $\forall v \in S \cap T$.

Am I correct so far?

From there I'm not too sure how to show that $y \in span\{S \cap T \}$

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What you are trying to prove is not true. For example, let $S = \{ (1,0), (0,1)\}$ and $T = \{(1,1), (1,-1)\}$. Then $S \cap T = \emptyset$, but each of $S$ and $T$ span all of $\mathbb R^2$. Do you see what's wrong?

Comment: Could we say it's false because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not a subset of the zero vector? Also, is this always false?

Comment: It's not even true in $1$ dimension. In $\mathbb R$ we have  $span (\{1\})=span (\{2\})=\mathbb R$ but $span (\{1\}\cap \{2\})=span (\phi)=\phi. $The inclusion should be the other way around.